# How to stop Backbone route event before trigger the function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I want to be able to stop the route trigger in "before" function. The function above is working great. It calls "before" method correctly. Is there any suitable way to stop route when "before" method is called?

**Update: Solved!**

```
(function () {
    _.extend(Backbone.Router.prototype, Backbone.Events, {        
        route: function (route, name, callback) {           
            if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);
            if (!callback) callback = this[name];
            var router = this;
            Backbone.history.route(route, _.bind(function (fragment) {               
                var args = this._extractParameters(route, fragment);                

                if (_.isFunction(router.before)) {
                  if (router.before.apply(this, args) === false) return;
                }
                callback && callback.apply(this, args);
                this.trigger.apply(this, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
                if (_.isFunction(router.after)) {
                    router.after.apply(router, args);
                }
                Backbone.history.trigger('route', this, name, args);
            }, this));
            return this;
        }
    });
}).call(this);
```

And here is the router code:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
      '': 'home',
      'help(/)': 'help', // about or /about/
      'page(/:id)(/)' : 'page',
      '*path'  : 'notFound'
    },
    before: function () {
      return false; // the magic
    },
    after: function () {
    },
});
```

It works that way. return false can stop the process now. Perfect. The solution based on knpsck's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`before` and`after` hooks - is extra functionality. You can implement it this way (Backbone 1.1.2)

```
Backbone.Router.prototype.route: function(route, name, callback) {
      if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);

      if (_.isFunction(name)) {
        callback = name;
        name = '';
      }

      if (!callback) callback = this[name];

      var router = this;

      Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
        var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);

        if (_.isFunction(router.before)) {
            if (router.before.apply(this, args) === false) return;
        }

        router.execute(callback, args);

        if (_.isFunction(router.after)) {
            router.after.apply(router, args);
        }

        router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
        router.trigger('route', name, args);
        Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
      });

      return this;
}
```

Comment: Yes! It works! I had to edit a little. For example there is a missing `)` in `if (_.isFunction(router.after) {` line. And i had to a to wrapper to the beginning of the function. Please look at the updated question.

Comment: yeah, missed bracket. Updated

Comment: Sorry but your extension calls before and after at the same time. I merge your code with somebody else's code. I modified the code and works great now. Please see the updated question again.

Comment: In my opinion `after` should be called immediately after executing callback, not after event triggering. But you can use as you wish ;) Also i suggest to use native backbone's `router.execute(callback, args)` instead of `callback && callback.apply(this, args)`. Look http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-162